# Output every file status in a git tree

Tags: git

I'm trying to output the name and status of every file (tracked or untracked) in a git working tree - preferably in an machine-readable format - but I cannot find any git command to do this.

`git-status` and `git-diff` only seem to have options to show modified and untracked files - even in verbose mode, they do not list tracked, unchanged files.

The closest I can find is `git ls-files -t -cdmo` which is pretty much what  I want (lists every file with a status tag) but the command is listed as semi-deprecated.

Is there an alternative I should be using? - I find it hard to believe that git does not possess a simple "*list all files with status*" command.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge `git ls-files -t` is semi-deprecated simply in favor of `git ls-files -v`, which ought to have the only difference of being able to tell you also about the *assume unchanged* bit (by using lowercase letters for the files that have it set).